# Linear transformation that is onto and singular. (And non-singular but not onto.)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm trying to do the following question:

> Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix with entries in $\mathbb{F}$ and let
>   $T$ be the linear transformation from $\mathbb{F}^{n\times 1}$ into
>   $\mathbb{F}^{m\times1}$ defined by $T(X)=AX$. Show that if $m<n$ it
>   may happen that $T$ in onto without being non-singular. Similarly,
>   show that if $m>n$ we may have $T$ non-singular but not onto.

I know that if $m=n$, then $T$ being onto is equivalent to being non-singular. I just can't find any examples for it to be wrong when $m>n$ or $m<n$.

Comment: What does it mean for $T$ to be singular, when $m \neq n$?

Comment: @Cat:  It's a reasonable request for clarification, but I take it to mean that the kernel is nontrivial (i.e. not 1-1 in the case of a linear transformation).

Comment: @Cal, hardmath nailed it.

Comment: Well then the statement should say 1-1, not nonsingular, as that is a special term referring to the case $n=m$. Anyway, this is often shown using the rank + nullity theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\ x_n\end{bmatrix}, A=[A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n]$ where $A_i$'s are the columns of $A.$

(i) $m<n$

Choose the first $m$ columns of $A$ to be any set of '$m$' linearly independent vectors in $F^{m\times 1}.$ Then $T$ is onto since $T(X)=AX=x_1A_1+x_2A_2+\ldots x_mA_m+\ldots x_nA_n.$ Also we know a non-trivial solution exists for $X$ in $AX=0$ since $m<n.$

Thus it may happen that $T$ is onto without being non-singular.

(ii)$m>n$

Choose any '$n$' linearly independent set of vectors from $F^{m\times 1}$ to be the columns of $A.$ Then $T$ wouldn't span $F^{m\times 1}$ since $T(X)=x_1A_1+x_2A_2+\ldots x_nA_n$ and these '$n$' vectors certainly would not span since $m>n.$ Also $T(X)=0\implies x_1A_1+x_2A_2+\ldots x_nA_n=0\implies x_i=0, 1\le i\le n.\implies X=0$

Thus we may have $T$ non-singular but not onto.